# Why does fit_transform with OneHotEncoding not maintain the transformation for my X variable?

Tags: python, pipeline, one-hot-encoding

I am using a pipeline to transform my X variable that has categorical features using OneHotEncoding; however, even after I fit_transfrom X, when I print X, I still see categorical values:

```
X = df.drop('Loan_Status', axis='columns')
y = df['Loan_Status']

from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

column_trans = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(), ['Loan_ID', 'Gender', 'Married', 'Education',
                      'Self_Employed','Property_Area']),
    remainder='passthrough')

column_trans.fit_transform(X)
```

Am I missing a step to ensure my X variable maintains the encoded features?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `column_trans.fit_transform` does not operate in-place. You need to assign the output to a variable.

Comment: I attributed the column_trans to X, and I get a sparse matrix, but then train_test_split provides the following error: "ValueError: Cannot center sparse matrices: pass `with_mean=False` instead. See docstring for motivation and alternatives."